# Matplotlib estimates width of text wrong

Tags: pdf, fonts, matplotlib

When using Matplotlib (Pylab) for rendering Text with the same metrics as AriaL (e.g., Arial itself or Liberation Sans) output looks ok - e.g., the width of the legend box is right.

However, when using other fonts it seems that Matplotlib wrongly estimates the expected size of the text. For example, with Bitstream Vera Sans the text seems to be wider than expected by Matplotlib: E.g., the right-hand side of the text sometimes overlaps with the right-hand side of the legend's box.

Similiarly, when using use_latex to let Latex render the output the text seems to be narrower than expected, and there's an additional space between the right-hand side of the text and the legend's box.

Is this a bug in Matplotlib? Or am I expected to use fonts with the metrics of Arial?

Comment: it would be useful if you post your example..

Answer (score 0):

I'm running matplotlib version 0.99.1.1 on linux (ubuntu 10.04) and cannot reproduce the problem.  Here is the code I'm using.

```
import pylab
a = [1,2,1]
label = "This long label isn't too long."
for family in ['Arial', 'Liberation Sans', 'Bitstream Vera Sans']:
    pylab.figure()
    pylab.plot(a)
    pylab.legend([label], prop={'family':family})
pylab.show()
```